# Powershell misunderstand quotation marks in a file name

Tags: powershell, batch-file, filenames

Yes these files do have quotation marks in the file name.!!

I am trying to run a bat file using a powershell script. Powershell script iterate through a folder and extract files. It then pass these file names to the batch script which calls an exe to process them.

This is what the powershell script looks like,

```
$path = "\\RemoteMachine\Japanese\files"
$filter = "*.msg"
$count = 0

Write-Host "Parsing started...";
get-childitem -recurse -path $path -filter $filter| % {
    $count++;
    & "C:\Users\uname\myfolder\runCommads.bat" "$($_.FullName)" "C:\Users\uname\myfolder\output\$count.txt"

}
```

The input files were written using a different language. Some files' names consist of quotation marks. When PS script runs runCommand.bat, spaces that contain in the file name are misinterpreted. A Word that succeeds a space is considered as a name of a different file.

But if I run the batch file without PS script, for just one file that contains quotation marks in the file name, the expected out is given.

Could someone help me with a solution for this problem?
Thank you

Comment: I tried your code and it worked for different files. with single quotes, spaces etc.  I suspect that the batch file cannot handle some files. With echo on you can follow what is exactly passed to your commands in the batch file. Sometimes double quotes are added, sometimes not.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem of the batch file not of the powershell script.

Normally the batch parser splits the parameters at spaces.
It can be suppressed by using quotes, but if your filename itself contains quotes it will again fail.

But you could double all quotes in the filename (inside the powershell script),
then it should be possible to get the correct filenames in the batch file.

Inside the batch you need to remove the doubled quotes, but that seems to be easy.

```
set "filename=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "filename=!filename:""="!"
```

But I suppose, that the most batch commands will fail with such filenames.